# Python dataframe: Select range of elements from one column matching data from another column

Tags: python, dataframe

```
diff = [10,15,20,25,20,15, 10, 10, 15, 21, 24, 19, 15, 10, 10, 15, 20, 21, 26, 20, 10,15, 20, 25, 20, 15, 10]
df_data = pd.DataFrame(diff, columns=['data']) 
df_data.insert(0, 'slno', [ d for d in range(0, df_data.shape[0])])

max = {
    'pos':[3,10,18,23],
    'val' :[25, 24, 26, 25]
     }
df_max = pd.DataFrame(max)

Dataframes what I have now:
df_data:

|     |slno|data |
|-----|----|-----|
|0    |  0 |   10|
|1    |  1 |   15|
|2    |  2 |   20|
|3    |  3 |   25|
|4    |  4 |   20|
|5    |  5 |   15|
|6    |  6 |   10|
|7    |  7 |   10|
|8    |  8 |   15|
|9    |  9 |   21|
|10   | 10 |   24|
|11   | 11 |   19|
|12   | 12 |   15|
|13   | 13 |   10|
|14   | 14 |   10|
|15   | 15 |   15|
|16   | 16 |   20|
|17   | 17 |   21|
|18   | 18 |   26|
|19   | 19 |   20|
|20   | 20 |   10|
|21   | 21 |   15|
|22   | 22 |   20|
|23   | 23 |   25|
|24   | 24 |   20|
|25   | 25 |   15|
|26   | 26 |   10|

df_max:

|   |pos|  val|
|---|---|-----|
|0  |  3|   25|
|1  | 10|   24|
|2  | 18|   26|
|3  | 23|   25|


Result Expected: 
df_max:

|   |pos  |val  |range               |
|---|-----|-----|--------------------|
|0  |  3  | 25  |[15, 20, 25, 20, 15]|
|1  | 10  | 24  |[15, 21, 24, 19, 15]|
|2  | 18  | 26  |[20, 21, 26, 20, 10]|
|3  | 23  | 25  |[15, 20, 25, 20, 15]|
```

I have two data frames. One data frame is selected rows of another. Now I need to go back to the bigger data frame, select data, and add the result to the smaller data frame.

df_data has all the data. df_max has position and value (higher than the predefined threshold, here it is 23). Now I need to pick 2 values before and 2 after the value that has crossed the threshold. Add this resulting list as a row element in df_max.

I am not able to wrap my head around it. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to select elements from `df_data['data']` according to the `pos` value in `df_max`:

```py
df_max['range'] = df_max['pos'].apply(lambda p:df_data.loc[p-2:p+2, 'data'].to_list())
```

Output:

```
   pos  val                 range
0    3   25  [15, 20, 25, 20, 15]
1   10   24  [15, 21, 24, 19, 15]
2   18   26  [20, 21, 26, 20, 10]
3   23   25  [15, 20, 25, 20, 15]
```